# Change theme of Android application instantly

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I want to change theme of the application from a fragment,I use

```
getActivity().getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.customTheme,true);
```

It works but after some switching between fragments it happens.
I want to change it instantly.
you may tell me to call recreate method:

```
getActivity().getTheme();
```

but it leads to an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction
    at android.app.ActivityInjector.checkAccessControl(ActivityInjector.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.onResume(Activity.java:1995)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:434)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1457)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:8264)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4494)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4536)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ClientTransactionHandler.executeTransaction(ClientTransactionHandler.java:58)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityLocally(ActivityThread.java:5498)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3400(ActivityThread.java:244)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2114)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7861)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:600)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Any ideas to do this?

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Ok, I've added full exception